# Копировать все с начала строки до последнего пробела

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe7

Вот так копировать все до первого пробела

```
s:=copy(s,1,pos(' ',s)-1);
```

Вот так копировать все до второго пробела

```
s:=copy(s,2,pos(' ',s)-1);
```

А вот как копировать все до последнего пробела с начала строки?

То есть строки вида:

```
str str str 123
str str 555
str 777
```

И на выходе результат:

```
str str str
str str
str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

прошу прощения, лет сто уже живого delphi не видел. Вам нужна функция LastDelimiter (последнее вхождение), и в целом как-то так будет

```
uses SysUtils;
var
  p:integer;
  str: string;
  str2: string;
   
begin
 str:='111 222 333 444';
 p:=LastDelimiter(' ',str);
 str2:=copy(str,1,p-1);
 
 writeln(str2);
 
end.
```

Comment: Tatarincev, Работает Идеально ! Спасибо!